# Method Parameter id similar to Class Field Best Practice?

Tags: language-agnostic

I have some methods which their parameters are related to the fields, and have the same ids or similar ids.

Some programmming languages doesn't allow this, some do, which do you consider a "Best Practice" (for cross-language) ?

(The example is C++ alike, but apply to any progr. lang.)

Example:

```
public class AnyClass {
  private string FilePath = "";

  public void assignPath(string FilePath) { ... }; // <-- same as field member

  public void assignPath(string AFilePath) { ... }; // <-- has a prefix

  public void assignPath(string filePath) { ... }; // <--  different case
}
```

Cheers.

UPDATE: add "cross language"

Comment: It will depend very heavily on the programming language. If you want to know for C++, ask about C++.

Comment: @Matt Ball, Since I work I regulary worj with several programming languages, I was thinking in a language-independent solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One thing for sure. Don't use parameter names starting with capital letter. I haven't seen those as best practices in any language I know. Same for fields that are not public.

I like the third option in your example.

Comment: I regulary use properties and fields Capitalized and methods with lowerCamelCase, but parameters I don't follow any given rule, but Capitlized seems to confuse me with methods.

Answer (score 0):

In general I believe "PascalCase" is used to denote static fields, and "camelCase" is used for instance fields. Also, as a general rule of thumb all method arguments should probably be "camelCase" or just "lower" if possible (I think a short truncation for a method argument is fine due to the limited scope).

However, I don't think having your method parameter arguments match exactly to instance field names is ideal in any situation. As far as prefixes go, any Hungarian notation should probably be avoided.